# ADO .addnew with ODBC for mariadb: Error

Tags: mysql, odbc, mariadb, ado

I am working on a proof of concept to migrate a small access application to MariaDB. 
For the proof of concept I used the code listed in the mysql odbc developer guide:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-programming-vb-ado.html

All the example code works fine until the following section where I get an error at "rs.Update"(cannot update record). All permissions are granted for the user.

`'rs insert
    rs.Open "select * from my_ado", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    rs.AddNew
    rs!Name = "Monty"
    rs!txt = "Insert row"
    rs.Update
    rs.Close`

I am using MariaDB 10.1.19 and MariaDB Connector/ODBC 2.0.16 on a Win7 64 bit platform.

Any help would be appreciated...

Edit: Last lines of odbc trace:

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLColAttributesW 
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        3 
        UWORD                       16 
        PTR                0x0D267D00
        SWORD                      258 
        SWORD *             0x0018D2DC
        SQLLEN *            0x00000000

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLColAttributesW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        3 
        UWORD                       16 
        PTR                0x0D267D00
        SWORD                      258 
        SWORD *             0x0018D2DC
        SQLLEN *            0x00000000

```
    DIAG [S1C00] [ma-1.0.6][10.1.19-MariaDB]Optional feature not implemented (0)
```

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 
        SQLHANDLE           0x004F1F30
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018D260
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0018CE38
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018CE60 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0018CE48

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 
        SQLHANDLE           0x004F1F30
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018D260 [       5] "S1C00"
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0018CE38 (0)
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018CE60 [      59] "[ma-1.0.6][10.1.19-MariaDB]Optional feature not implemented"
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0018CE48 (59)

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 
        SQLHANDLE           0x004F1F30
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018D260
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0018CE38
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018CE60 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0018CE48

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 
        SQLHANDLE           0x004F1F30
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018D260
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0018CE38
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018CE60 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0018CE48

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLColAttributesW 
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        3 
        UWORD                       23 
        PTR                0x0D267E10
        SWORD                      386 
        SWORD *             0x0018D2DC
        SQLLEN *            0x00000000

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLColAttributesW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        3 
        UWORD                       23 
        PTR                0x0D267E10
        SWORD                      386 
        SWORD *             0x0018D2DC (12)
        SQLLEN *            0x00000000

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLColAttributesW 
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        3 
        UWORD                       22 
        PTR                0x0D267FA0
        SWORD                      386 
        SWORD *             0x0018D2DC
        SQLLEN *            0x00000000

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLColAttributesW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        3 
        UWORD                       22 
        PTR                0x0D267FA0
        SWORD                      386 
        SWORD *             0x0018D2DC (6)
        SQLLEN *            0x00000000

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLColAttributesW 
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        3 
        UWORD                       13 
        PTR                0x00000000
        SWORD                        0 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        SQLLEN *            0x0018D2C8

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLColAttributesW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        3 
        UWORD                       13 
        PTR                0x00000000
        SWORD                        0 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        SQLLEN *            0x0018D2C8

```
    DIAG [S1C00] [ma-1.0.6][10.1.19-MariaDB]Optional feature not implemented (0)
```

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 
        SQLHANDLE           0x004F1F30
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018D244
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0018CE1C
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018CE44 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0018CE2C

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 
        SQLHANDLE           0x004F1F30
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018D244 [       5] "S1C00"
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0018CE1C (0)
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018CE44 [      59] "[ma-1.0.6][10.1.19-MariaDB]Optional feature not implemented"
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0018CE2C (59)

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 
        SQLHANDLE           0x004F1F30
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018D244
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0018CE1C
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018CE44 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0018CE2C

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 
        SQLHANDLE           0x004F1F30
        SQLSMALLINT                  2 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018D244
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0018CE1C
        SQLWCHAR *          0x0018CE44 
        SQLSMALLINT                512 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x0018CE2C

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLFreeStmt 
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        2

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLFreeStmt  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        2

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLFreeStmt 
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        0

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLFreeStmt  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        0

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLFreeStmt 
        HSTMT               0x004F3040
        UWORD                        1

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLFreeStmt  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x004F3040
        UWORD                        1

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLFreeStmt 
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        0

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLFreeStmt  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        0

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLFreeStmt 
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        1

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLFreeStmt  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x004F1F30
        UWORD                        1

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLDisconnect 
        HDBC                0x004F1AC0

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLDisconnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HDBC                0x004F1AC0

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLFreeConnect 
        HDBC                0x004F1AC0

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLFreeConnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HDBC                0x004F1AC0

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLFreeEnv 
        HENV                0x004F17B0

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLFreeEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x004F17B0

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   ENTER SQLFreeEnv 
        HENV                0x004F1828

Valuation and B 1ad8-1f28   EXIT  SQLFreeEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x004F1828

Comment: Please provide the exact error, including SQLSTATEs and so on.

Comment: Error Number is -2147467259. I am not sure, what you mean with SQLSTATE. I do have a odbc trace file, but I cannot attach it here.

Comment: After some reasearch found some indication:  DIAG [S1C00] [ma-2.0.13][10.1.19-MariaDB]Optional feature not implemented (0). Unfortunately I cannot put it in context? Is this a MariaDB bug?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Besides some other issues, this update-error was driving me nuts, because despite of this error the first record was added to the maria-db. When i tested from scratch, i found this error only occurs, when at the time of the upadte command there are other recordsets open too.
As i did not want to rewrite my access code, the first quick and dirty trial was to wrap the update command in a 'on error resume next'. That resolved the matter.

e.g.

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("...")
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(".....")
....
Do While Not rs.EOF
  rs2.AddNew
  rs2.Fields("...") = rs.Fields("...")
  rs2.Fields("...") = rs.Fields("...")
  ....
  ....
  On Error Resume Next
  rs2.Update
  On Error GoTo 0
Loop
....
```

I hope, this will work for you too.
Please be also awre of potential problems with date and time fields.